# How to increase the spacing between organization name and job title in awesome-cv

Tags: awesome-cv

I'm working on awesome-cv. I've been able to play with the spacing somewhat, but I'm having trouble modifying the spacing within cv entries between say organization name and position title, or between position title and the bullet-points.
I think I have the right section of awesome-cv.cls to focus on, but not sure what to change.

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
       %%% I believe the lines above are what I should be focusing on, but haven't had success with inserting \vspace   
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
    \vspace{3mm}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Unfortunately your code is not complete enough to help you. Please add its beginning (\documentclass you are using, \usepackage etc.) AND its end. I.e. please provide everything so we can copy, paste and run your code ... or see at a glance problem and solution. // Thanks.